# Objects not displaying in GUI - Java

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt

I made a simple GUI in Java, which includes a menu, context menu, button, toolbar, check box and status bar. However, the button and toolbar are not displaying. This is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class test extends JFrame {

private JLabel statusbar;
private JPopupMenu menu;
private Toolkit toolkit;

public test() {

    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    toolkit = this.getToolkit();
    menu = new JPopupMenu();
    JToolBar toolbar1 = new JToolBar();
    JToolBar toolbar2 = new JToolBar();

    ImageIcon iconNew = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("new.png")); // Icons
    ImageIcon iconOpen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("open.png"));
    ImageIcon iconSave = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("save.png"));
    ImageIcon iconExit = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("exit.png"));

    JButton newb = new JButton(iconNew); // Declaring Buttons for Toolbar
    JButton openb = new JButton(iconOpen);
    JButton saveb = new JButton(iconSave);
    JButton exitb = new JButton(iconExit);

    toolbar1.add(newb); // Adding Buttons to Toolbar1
    toolbar1.add(openb);
    toolbar1.add(saveb);
    toolbar1.setAlignmentX(0); // Alignment of Toolbar1

    toolbar2.add(exitb); // Adding Buttons to Toolbar2
    toolbar2.setAlignmentX(0); // Alignment of Toolbar2

    exitb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });

    panel.add(toolbar1);
    panel.add(toolbar2);

    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar(); // JMenuBar
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu view = new JMenu("View");
    file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

    JMenuItem eMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit", iconExit); // Exit Menu Item
    eMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    eMenuItem.setToolTipText("Exit application");
    eMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W,
            ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    eMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    JMenuItem nMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New", iconNew); // New Menu Item
    nMenuItem.setToolTipText("New File");
    JMenuItem oMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open", iconOpen);
    oMenuItem.setToolTipText("Open File");
    JMenuItem sMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Save", iconSave);
    sMenuItem.setToolTipText("Save File");

    JMenu imp = new JMenu("Import..."); // Import Sub-Menu Item
    imp.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_M);
    imp.setToolTipText("Import Data");
    JMenuItem newsf = new JMenuItem("Import newsfeed list...");
    JMenuItem bookm = new JMenuItem("Import bookmarks...");
    JMenuItem mail = new JMenuItem("Import mail...");

    imp.add(newsf); // Adding Sub-menu Items to Menu
    imp.add(bookm);
    imp.add(mail);

    file.add(nMenuItem); // Adding Menu Items to "File" Menu-List
    file.add(oMenuItem);
    file.add(sMenuItem);
    file.addSeparator();
    file.add(imp);
    file.addSeparator();
    file.add(eMenuItem);

    JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit"); // Quit Button
    quitButton.setBounds(870, 380, 80, 30);
    quitButton.setToolTipText("Press me");
    quitButton.setBackground(new Color(66, 89, 205));
    quitButton.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next >"); // Next Button
    nextButton.setBounds(770, 380, 80, 30);
    nextButton.setToolTipText("Next...");
    nextButton.setBackground(new Color(66, 89, 205));

    nextButton.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));

    nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    panel.add(quitButton); // Adding Buttons to panel
    panel.add(nextButton);

    JCheckBoxMenuItem sbar = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Show StatuBar"); // Creating
                                                                        // Status-bar
                                                                        // Check-box
    sbar.setState(true);
    sbar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (statusbar.isVisible()) {
                statusbar.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                statusbar.setVisible(true);
            }
        }

    });

    view.add(sbar); // Adding Check-box to the View Menu-List

    JMenuItem menuItemBeep = new JMenuItem("Beep"); // Beep option in Pop-Up
    menuItemBeep.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            toolkit.beep();
        }
    });

    menubar.add(file); // Adding Menu-Lists to Menu Bar
    menubar.add(view);

    menu.add(menuItemBeep); // Adding Beep option in Pop-Up

    JMenuItem menuItemClose = new JMenuItem("Close"); // Close option in
                                                        // Pop-Up
    menuItemClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    menu.add(menuItemClose); // Adding Close option in Pop-Up

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { // Mouse Listener for Pop-Up
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    });

    setJMenuBar(menubar); // Menu-bar???

    statusbar = new JLabel(" Statusbar"); // Creating Status Bar
    statusbar.setBorder(BorderFactory
            .createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
    add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    panel.setLayout(null); // Panel Design and additional Arguments
    panel.setBackground(new Color(18, 33, 110));

    this.setTitle("My First GUI in Java");
    this.setSize(1000, 500);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            test ex = new test();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

I'm very new to this so any comments are appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You probably shouldn't extend JFrame, and you seem to be adding the panel twice.

Comment: Where do you call `implements ActionListener`?

Comment: You've got a bunch of components. Which ones aren't displaying? I would recommend boiling your problem down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and eliminating all of the extra code. You also seem to be adding the same panel to both the content pane and the JFrame (which just passes it along to the content pane anyway), which indicates that you might want to go through your code with a fine-toothed comb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"However, the button and toolbar are not displaying."*

1. Looking through your `init()` method, I only see you adding two components to your frame.

   ```
   add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   ```
2. Then with the same panel as above, you set the layout to null, when you first already specified it to be a `BoxLayout`

   ```
   panel.setLayout(null);
   ```
3. I comment the above code out, and some components appear.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the Layout of panel twice once at beginning:

> panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

and once later on:

> panel.setLayout(null);

You should try getting rid of the second one. That should fix the problem